AutoMapper.Extensions.OData wrong SQL query for compare nullable DateTime and DateOnly
For all OData endpoints in my ASP.NET Core Web API, I return value in this way:
{
    "@odata.context": "...",
    "@odata.count": 0,
    "value": [...]
}

When I set filter like this for my DateTime column:
(datetime%20ge%202024-08-21T21%3A00%3A00Z)

The script executes the query like this to count the matching rows:
SELECT count(*)
FROM table0 AS p
INNER JOIN table1 AS p0 ON p.table1_id = p0.table1_id
WHERE CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM table2_id AS r
                 WHERE p.table0_id = r.table0_id) 
        THEN (SELECT r0.datetime
              FROM table2_id AS r0
              WHERE p.table0_id = r0.table0_id
              LIMIT 1)
    ELSE TIMESTAMPTZ '-infinity'
END >= $3

but if filter is only for date without time:
(datetime%20ge%202024-08-21)

The script is change into something like this:
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table0 
INNER JOIN table1 ON p.table1_id = p0.table1_id 
WHERE DATE_PART('year', CASE WHEN EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE p.table0_id = r.table0_id 
) THEN ( 
    SELECT r0.datetime 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE p.table0_id = r0.table0_id 
    LIMIT 1 
) ELSE TIMESTAMPTZ '-infinity' END AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) :: int * 10000 + date_part ( 'month', CASE WHEN EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE p.table0_id = r1.table0_id 
) THEN ( 
    SELECT r2.datetime 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE p.table0_id = r2.table0_id 
    LIMIT 1 
) ELSE TIMESTAMPTZ '-infinity' END AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) :: int * 100 + date_part ( 'day', CASE WHEN EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE p.table0_id = r3.table0_id 
) THEN ( 
    SELECT r4.datetime 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE p.table0_id = r4.table0_id 
    LIMIT 1 
) ELSE TIMESTAMPTZ '-infinity' END AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) :: int >= @__p_3

The problem arises when it fails to find a record and uses TIMESTAMPTZ '-infinity', it is unable to convert this to an int value and an error is thrown:

PostgresException (0x80004005): 22003: integer out of range

Tech stack:

.NET 8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.2.5
AutoMapper.AspNetCore.OData.EFCore 5.0.2


You have to isolate the issue. Can you make a repro with a simple LINQ query? Then maybe it's an issue with the Postgres provider.

If I find some free time, I'll try to do something like that.
